# Minimizing Java function call overhead

Tags: java, performance, optimization, java-8, jmh

I have [a piece of code](https://gist.github.com/ssube/c5d7769f3087aae10421) where it appears, in every test I've run, that function calls have a significant amount of overhead. The code is a tight loop, performing a very simple function on each element of an array (containing 4-8 million `int`s).

Running the code, which consists primarily of

```
for (int y = 1; y < h; ++y) {
    for (int x = 1; x < w; ++x) {
        final int p = y * s + x;
        n[p] = f.apply(d, s, x, y);
    }
}
```

executing something like

```
(final int[] d, final int s, final int x, final int y) -> {
    final int p = s * y + x;
    final int a = d[p] * 2
                + d[p - 1]
                + d[p + 1]
                + d[p - s]
                + d[p + s];
    return (1000 * (a + 500)) / 6000;
};
```

on various machines (my work laptop, a W530 with i7 3840QM, a server VM with one core of a Xeon E5-1620, and a Digital Ocean node with one core of an unknown CPU), I repeatedly get a statistically significant performance hit when calling a method vs inlining. All tests were performed on Java 1.8.0_11 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM).

*Work machine:*

```
Benchmark                               Mode   Samples        Score  Score error    Units
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessInline    thrpt       200       40.860        0.184    ops/s
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessLambda    thrpt       200       22.603        0.159    ops/s
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessProc      thrpt       200       22.792        0.117    ops/s
```

*Dedicated server, VM:*

```
Benchmark                               Mode   Samples        Score  Score error    Units
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessInline    thrpt       200       40.685        0.224    ops/s
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessLambda    thrpt       200       16.077        0.113    ops/s
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessProc      thrpt       200       23.827        0.088    ops/s
```

*DO VPS:*

```
Benchmark                               Mode   Samples        Score  Score error    Units
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessInline    thrpt       200       24.425        0.506    ops/s
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessLambda    thrpt       200        9.643        0.140    ops/s
c.s.q.ShaderBench.testProcessProc      thrpt       200       13.733        0.134    ops/s
```

All acceptable performance, but I am interested in figuring out why the call has such significant overhead and what can be done to optimize that. Currently experimenting with different sets of parameters.

Inlining all the potential operations would be difficult, but theoretically possible. For close to a 2x performance increase, potentially worth it, but maintenance would be a nightmare.

I'm not sure if there's a reasonable way to batch up a set of repetitions; most of the operations take multiple inputs (unknown to the caller) and produce a single output.

What other options do I have for minimizing the overhead and evening out performance?

Comment: FYI to people who want to answer, the `f` function is actually a normal interface method, not a `@functionalInterface`

Comment: @dkatzel That's a mistake on my part (this is part of a project to play with Java 8), although one that could be kept if it helps in some way. It's fairly important `f` be fillable by a class or lambda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method call is not a problem since hot methods are often inlined. A **virtual** call is an issue.

In your code the type profiler is fooled by the initialization method `Image.random`. When `Image.process` is JIT-compiled for the first time, it is optimized for calling `random.nextInt()`. So the next invocations of `Image.process` will result in the inline-cache miss followed by a non-optimized virtual call to `Shader.apply`.

1. Remove an `Image.process` call from the initialization method and JIT will then inline the useful calls to `Shader.apply`.
2. After `BlurShader.apply` is inlined you can help JIT to perform [Common subexpression elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) optimization by replacing

   ```
   final int p = s * y + x;
   ```

   with

   ```
   final int p = y * s + x;
   ```

   The latter expression is also met in `Image.process`, so JIT will not calculate the same expression twice.

After applying these two changes I've achieved the ideal benchmark score:

```
Benchmark                           Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
s.ShaderBench.testProcessInline    thrpt         5       36,483        1,255    ops/s
s.ShaderBench.testProcessLambda    thrpt         5       36,323        0,936    ops/s
s.ShaderBench.testProcessProc      thrpt         5       36,163        1,421    ops/s
```

Comment: The reason there's an interface involved, and the apply method is in another class, is because that part is pluggable and can't be inlined (manually). For the example/benchmark, there's only one filter implemented. Preventing `Image.random` from being inlined does sound helpful. Is it possible for the JVM to keep multiple versions of `Image.process` with different functions inlined? Any standards or convention around that?

Comment: For some additional detail, hopefully of use, I plan to have 4-6 layers (`Image`s) of different sizes, each processed once or twice per second, each using a different filter. I'm trying to avoid making `Image` abstract and writing 4-6 subclasses.

Comment: @ssube HotSpot JVM can inline up to 2 most frequently used implementations of an interface into a single call site. There will be a virtual method call for other implementations. This is just a behavior of a particular JVM, not covered by any convention. To see the actual JIT inlining activity use the following JVM options: `-XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining`.

Comment: If you find the real scenario performance unsatisfactory, I would suggest to create separate `process` methods for each filter so that these methods will process the whole image, not just one pixel.

Comment: It seems like that may be the only viable option. I'll have to refactor the interfaces a bit to keep things clean, but it will probably work acceptably well.