# jvm jit common subexpression elimination

Tags: java, jvm, jit

Testing the following snippet using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

```
class A {
    public int test(int i) {
        long sum = 0L;
        for (int j=0; j<i; ++j) {
            sum += 1 << (j % 32);
        }
        return (int)sum;
    }
}

@State(Scope.Thread)
public class MyBenchmark {
    public A a;
    int x;

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void init() {
        a = new A();
        x = 1;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int testMethod() {
        int res = 0;
        res += a.test(x);
        res += a.test(x);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Build and run the example using `mvn package && java -XX:-UseCompressedOops -XX:CompileCommand='print, *.testMethod' -jar target/benchmarks.jar -wi 10 -i 1 -f 1` to get the following assembly (only showing the assembly for the final compilation).

```
ImmutableOopMap{}pc offsets: 762 772 800 Compiled method (c2)     397  551       4       org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod (32 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007f96dd74bd90,0x00007f96dd74c170] = 992
 relocation     [0x00007f96dd74bed0,0x00007f96dd74bee0] = 16
 main code      [0x00007f96dd74bee0,0x00007f96dd74bfa0] = 192
 stub code      [0x00007f96dd74bfa0,0x00007f96dd74bfb8] = 24
 oops           [0x00007f96dd74bfb8,0x00007f96dd74bfc0] = 8
 metadata       [0x00007f96dd74bfc0,0x00007f96dd74bfd0] = 16
 scopes data    [0x00007f96dd74bfd0,0x00007f96dd74c038] = 104
 scopes pcs     [0x00007f96dd74c038,0x00007f96dd74c168] = 304
 dependencies   [0x00007f96dd74c168,0x00007f96dd74c170] = 8
----------------------------------------------------------------------
org/sample/MyBenchmark.testMethod()I  [0x00007f96dd74bee0, 0x00007f96dd74bfb8]  216 bytes
Argument 0 is unknown.RIP: 0x7f96dd74bee0 Code size: 0x000000d8
[Entry Point]
[Constants]
  # {method} {0x00007f95ed0efe80} 'testMethod' '()I' in 'org/sample/MyBenchmark'
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x00007f96dd74bee0: cmp     0x8(%rsi),%rax
  0x00007f96dd74bee4: jne     0x7f96d5c99c60    ;   {runtime_call ic_miss_stub}
  0x00007f96dd74beea: nop
  0x00007f96dd74beec: nopl    0x0(%rax)
[Verified Entry Point]
  0x00007f96dd74bef0: mov     %eax,0xfffffffffffec000(%rsp)
  0x00007f96dd74bef7: push    %rbp
  0x00007f96dd74bef8: sub     $0x10,%rsp        ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@-1 (line 66)

  0x00007f96dd74befc: mov     0x10(%rsi),%r11d  ;*getfield x {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@8 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf00: mov     0x18(%rsi),%r10
  0x00007f96dd74bf04: test    %r10,%r10
  0x00007f96dd74bf07: je      0x7f96dd74bf73    ;*invokevirtual test {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf09: xor     %eax,%eax
  0x00007f96dd74bf0b: test    %r11d,%r11d
  0x00007f96dd74bf0e: jle     0x7f96dd74bf67    ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@8 (line 46)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf10: xor     %r10d,%r10d
  0x00007f96dd74bf13: xor     %r9d,%r9d
  0x00007f96dd74bf16: xor     %r8d,%r8d
  0x00007f96dd74bf19: mov     $0x1,%edi         ;*ishl {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@18 (line 47)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf1e: movsxd  %edi,%rcx
  0x00007f96dd74bf21: add     %rcx,%r8          ;*ladd {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@20 (line 47)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf24: incl    %r9d              ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@22 (line 46)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf27: cmp     %r11d,%r9d
  0x00007f96dd74bf2a: jnl     0x7f96dd74bf3b    ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@8 (line 46)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf2c: mov     %r9d,%ecx
  0x00007f96dd74bf2f: and     $0x1f,%ecx
  0x00007f96dd74bf32: mov     $0x1,%edi
  0x00007f96dd74bf37: shl     %cl,%edi          ;*ishl {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@18 (line 47)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)

  0x00007f96dd74bf39: jmp     0x7f96dd74bf1e
  0x00007f96dd74bf3b: mov     $0x1,%r9d         ;*ishl {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@18 (line 47)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@25 (line 68)

  0x00007f96dd74bf41: movsxd  %r9d,%r9
  0x00007f96dd74bf44: add     %r9,%r10          ;*ladd {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@20 (line 47)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@25 (line 68)

  0x00007f96dd74bf47: incl    %eax              ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@22 (line 46)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@25 (line 68)

  0x00007f96dd74bf49: cmp     %r11d,%eax
  0x00007f96dd74bf4c: jnl     0x7f96dd74bf5e    ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@8 (line 46)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@25 (line 68)

  0x00007f96dd74bf4e: mov     %eax,%ecx
  0x00007f96dd74bf50: and     $0x1f,%ecx
  0x00007f96dd74bf53: mov     $0x1,%r9d
  0x00007f96dd74bf59: shl     %cl,%r9d          ;*ishl {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.A::test@18 (line 47)
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@25 (line 68)

  0x00007f96dd74bf5c: jmp     0x7f96dd74bf41
  0x00007f96dd74bf5e: mov     %r8d,%r11d
  0x00007f96dd74bf61: mov     %r10d,%eax
  0x00007f96dd74bf64: add     %r11d,%eax        ;*iadd {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@28 (line 68)

  0x00007f96dd74bf67: add     $0x10,%rsp
  0x00007f96dd74bf6b: pop     %rbp
  0x00007f96dd74bf6c: test    %eax,0x165a708e(%rip)  ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007f96dd74bf72: retq
  0x00007f96dd74bf73: mov     $0xfffffff6,%esi
  0x00007f96dd74bf78: mov     %r11d,%ebp
  0x00007f96dd74bf7b: callq   0x7f96d5c9b560    ; ImmutableOopMap{}
                                                ;*invokevirtual test {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)
                                                ;   {runtime_call UncommonTrapBlob}
  0x00007f96dd74bf80: callq   0x7f96f2772aa0    ;*invokevirtual test {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - org.sample.MyBenchmark::testMethod@11 (line 67)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007f96dd74bf85: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf86: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf87: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf88: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf89: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf8a: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf8b: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf8c: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf8d: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf8e: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf8f: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf90: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf91: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf92: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf93: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf94: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf95: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf96: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf97: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf98: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf99: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf9a: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf9b: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf9c: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf9d: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf9e: hlt
  0x00007f96dd74bf9f: hlt
[Exception Handler]
[Stub Code]
```

If I understand the assembly correct, Common subexpression elimination (CSE) is *not* performed for `a.test(x)`. I guess the direct reason is that different registers are used for the two calls, preventing (hindering) the JIT from doing CSE.

`test` is merely an example of pure method, that does nothing interesting. My intention is that `test(x)` is expensive enough for some `x` so that CSE would be beneficial.

I wonder if there's any way to enable CSE explicitly in this case or other similar scenarios. Or how CSE worsk in JIT in JVM.

### ENV:

openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, you look at the wrong method. This is not what is executed on the hot path. `MyBenchmark.testMethod` is inlined into the benchmark loop, and the most time is spent in a JMH-generated method like

```
org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testMethod_jmhTest::testMethod_avgt_jmhStub
```

You may check it by running JMH with `-prof perfasm` option.

---

Anyway, you've guessed right that CSE does not work in the given example. But not because of different registers (register allocation is performed late after most machine-independent optimizations), but just because the control flow is too complicated here. Generally, CSE in HotSpot is not applied on subgraphs with cycles (i.e. loops).

> I wonder if there's any way to enable CSE explicitly in this case or
>   other similar scenarios.

Well, of course, by doing this manually, i.e. by caching the method result in a temporary variable. HotSpot is not too smart in detecting common subexpressions: for example, `s*y+x` and `y*s+x` are treated as different expressions, but you  may help JIT by rewriting the code like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875316/3448419).